# how reliable is css3 pie

Tags: css, cross-browser, css3pie

I have just come across [CSS3 pie](http://css3pie.com/).

I was wondering how reliable it is to use? Will it work on all operating systems and are there any scenarios where it may not work?

Comment: My concerns with it are non-IE browsers that also don't support some CSS3 functions. Images will still need to be provided as a backup for these browsers, so it sort of defeats the object of CSS3 PIE as far as I can see! I'm willing to be proven wrong though, hence I put this as a comment rather than an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd imagine it's much more about browser than OS. This is why "virtualized" web front ends like Flex/Silverlight/JavaFX are popular now because all these concerns mostly go away.

It's difficult to say how *reliable* it is since it's ultimately reliant on the chaotic ever-changing browser environment. Something could break on the next update of IE/Firefox/Opera/Chrome/Safari, or it could work fine. (Actually it *says* it's only for IE 6-8, so if you're not okay with that, you may run into trouble?)

It'll probably (?) be hard finding someone with actual experience with this util. Don't forget to check the list of known issues: http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/

Comment: Actually, my company had a client who wanted to have the border-radius thingy working in IE7 and IE8 so the obvious solution was to use a tool like the PIE thing. It worked out great - but we only used it for border-radius and still needed to supply images for gradient backgrounds, custom styled textfields and such. But I confirm that it works.

Comment: I don't doubt that it works *now*, my concerns are more centered on the unpredictable future of the browser landscape and "non-standard standards".

Comment: IE9 has all the CSS3 effects that CSSPie provides, so it's fulfilling its mission of IE-compatibility for 6 through 8.

Comment: If it's essentially a 'legacy tool' (only IE 6-8 with no practical use after 8), you're probably okay, in that case. But just to be clear, what I'm trying to get at is that a future version of a browser can potentially break something one of these libs does simply because nobody can predict the future, and that would require a patch/fix to resolve.

Comment: @Micheal Mullany IE9 doesn't have `linear-gradient` (unless you use filter).

Answer (score 1):

Quite reliable, but only the most common CSS3 tags are supported. I tried it under IE7 and IE8, Windows XP, Windows 7 32 and 64 bit - works as expected in all cases.

I've never had a chance to test it under the OSX version of IE though.

My advice, however, would be to work your site with CSS2 and then add CSS3 magic only to add extra eye candy for browsers capable of displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

It works very well for staic elements.

But if you are planning on using animation on CSS PIE elements - you will probably encounter problems in older IE's.

I was developing dropdown menu with rounded corners and shadows. I could not make it work right for IE8 (IE7, IE9, FF, Chome, Safari, Opera was fine). After 10 hours of experimenting with zoom, inline-block, min-width hacks i had to build it old way.

Answer (score 1):

On my Windows Server 20008 that comes IE 8 64-Bit, PIE don't work, I tested there own site and mine, although I have not found any other posts about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So how is CSS3Pie travelling these days (2012)? Got a design with a heap of CSS3 goodness that needs to work in IE7+ I'm thinking of just sticking to the filter: progid...